# Get parent page/menu id of current post

Tags: menus, pages, hierarchical

Basically, after setting up the initial "page for post" on the Reading Options, and then add that page to the menu I get the posts when I click on that menu item as expected.

On there I know the post ID (which is the actual page created before setting it as the page for posts) and all the information regarding that same page.

Trouble is, when I click on a specific post, not only the menu item looses its active status, but I can't get hold of that parent page ID.

Is there a way to get that parent page ID, when on a post !?

**Edit:**
For reference, I managed to get it with `get_option('page_for_posts');` but that's very ugly. Is not possible that the post associates with it's parent page index ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want [`get_queried_object`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object). If you have set your static front page and blog page from `wp-admin->Settings->Reading` then `get_queried_object` will give you information about the page you chose rather than about the posts in the Loop.

Be aware that `get_queried_object` will return very different types of information depending on the kind of page you are on. From the Codex:

> - if you're on a single post, it will return the post object
> - if you're on a page, it will return the page object
> - if you're on a category archive, it will return the category object
> - etc.
>
>   http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object

On your posts page it should be a WP_Post object

```
$thispage = get_queried_object();
var_dump($thispage); // WP_Post object
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `global $post` before the loop?

Comment: Even with that. `$post->parent` comes empty. I managed to manually get it with `get_option('page_for_posts');` but that's not elegant at all

Comment: You're only setting that page as the posts page right? But that page not necessarily is a child of some other page. I think you need to use the ID of the global $post variable, and before the_loop begins.

Comment: Yes i've set it as the post page indeed. Should that page not be parent of any posts assigned to it ? What do you mean, use the ID of the global $post variable ? I tried it, and parent is empty.

Comment: Why do you need the parent? You just that post page's info right ? That page doesn't become the posts parent!