# How do I reference the front page's parent Page object?

Tags: pages, frontpage

I have created a "News" Page and have switched my posts-page to that Page. Now Posts show up under that Page, as desired.

The problem is I'm trying to access the core Page to pull out some information. On any other Page I could look to `$post` but in this setup, with blog posts being present, that variable is otherwise taken.

How do I reference the underlying Page object?

Comment: See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/102340/21376 Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the ID of the front page via [`get_option( 'page_on_front' )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option). (See also: [WordPress option reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Option_Reference).)

From there, you can query the page object via [`get_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post):

```
$frontpage = get_post( get_option( 'page_on_front' ) );
```

Then the content is in the `$frontpage` object:

```
$content = $frontpage->post_content;
```